# What can I connect to PC PSU output?

Tags: power-supply

I have a PSU similar to this one:

[image: http://www.asia.ru/images/target/photo/51500815/Computer_Power_Supply.jpg]

(Source: http://www.asia.ru/en/ProductInfo/972066.html)

I can see I can not only apply power to it, but also connect other devices. How much power can those draw?

Comment: Some people typically would plug in thier monitor to that additonal plug, however; most have stopped doing this.

Comment: @MattKing: why would they stop?

Comment: Power draw typically as well as connecting new monitors / pc's to surge protectors.

Comment: I opened one of these PSUs, and it turns out that the mains input is directly connected to the mains output (which people used for powering up their monitors.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier, people used to connect their display to this power outlet.

The main advantage was that this output is turned on and off with your computer, negating the need to manually manage the display’s power state.

Keep in mind that there was no such thing as [DPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling) back then, so the screen would not go to standby when the PC ceased to provide a signal.

This is also the main reason this outlet is no longer built into modern power supplies: With advanced power saving features, it is no longer needed.

Because there is no special eletronics involved, power draw is not limited. IEC 60320 (defines the C13/C14 socket/plug) specifies a maximum current of 10 A, US standards allow up to 15 A. People used to connect CRTs to this outlet, so it can take quite some load.